# Android - Webviewclient onReceivedHttpError determine if is main resource

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, http-error, webviewclient

`WebViewClient.onReceivedError` was deprecated, now I have to use `onReceivedHttpError` to handle the webview errors, however this method receives the error from any resource, which is not what I desire.

I wish only to detect the **main URL failing**.

How should I detect the error if I am using **API 10**?

I tried using the `request.getUrl()` method but it is only compatible with API 23.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile, I ended up doing this:

```
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                //your thing (f.e. show error message)
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                   //url is the original loading url
                    if(request.getUrl().equals(url)) { 
                        //your thing (f.e. show error message)
                    }
                }

            }
```