# How to detect errors only from the main page in new onReceivedError from WebViewClient

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

#### Context

In the Android SDK 23 `onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)` has been deprecated and replaced with `onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)`. However as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceError)):

> Note that unlike the deprecated version of the callback, the new
>   version will be called for any resource (iframe, image, etc), not just
>   for the main page

#### Problem

We have an app where in the deprecated `onReceivedError` method there is a code to display a native view instead of letting the user see the error in the WebView.

We would like to replace the deprecated `onReceivedError` method by the new method. But we don't want to display the native view for errors for any resource, just for the main page.

#### Question

How can we identify in the new `onReceivedError` that the error is not from the main page?

PS 1: We would prefer not having a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43664365/1401164) to store the main url and check it against the failing url.

PS 2: If the solution is to just use the deprecated method, what's the guarantee that it will still be called for new Android versions?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this correctly, ```to store the main url and check it against the failing url.```, why wouldn't you prefer that? Does the main page change or something?

Comment: yes, it changes as user navigates through the website

Comment: Got your point, thought that main page is like the home page of a website. Will your app still be released for pre-Lollipop devices?

Comment: Sorry, my bad previous comment is unnecessary nvm.

Could the main url be differentiated from the resources? Meaning page urls are of form http://www.myurl.com while resource for images are saved in cdn and so are of the form http://www.cdn.com etc...? If so you could use a regular expression and only filter the main urls? That is assuming if you're displaying your website within the app...

Comment: probably, but we'd rather not going through that path. the previous onReceivedError had a solution out of the box, we wonder if there is an alternative mechanism out of the box out there

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`WebResourceRequest` has `isForMainFrame()` method for your scenario which is available starting from API version 21:

[image]

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceRequest.html

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to store the original URL. You can get it from the `WebView` passed to the `onReceivedError` method. It's always the full URL of the current page that the user sees. So, you don't have to worry about them navigating to different pages.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    if (request.getUrl().toString().equals(view.getUrl())) {
        notifyError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use like as codes:

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
     wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
// here your custom logcat like as share preference or database or static varible.
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
     });
```

Best of luck!